# Catch-All URL in flask-restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

There is a [Catch-All URL](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/) ability in Flask

> ```
> from flask import Flask app = Flask(__name__)
>
> @app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
> @app.route('/<path:path>')
> def catch_all(path):
>     return 'You want path: %s' % path
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     app.run()
> ```
>
> A little demonstration..
>
> ```
> % curl 127.0.0.1:5000          # Matches the first rule
> You want path:  
> % curl 127.0.0.1:5000/foo/bar  # Matches the second rule
> You want path: foo/bar
> ```

How can I have the same functionality in `flask-restful`?

Comment: Isn't that just a standard Flask route with a `:path` mapping? The name `catch_all` could be anything

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe, I'm not that familiar with Flask, can I adopt the solution for restful-flask?

Comment: @cricket_007 not I'm not talking about the name of the function. I'm looking for a way to catch all sub addresses after `/`

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. Or why you need Flask-RESTful to accomplish that. You can map only one `Resource` to a `/`, I believe. See here. http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#resourceful-routing

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, I've already read that. I need to. sure there must be a way.

Comment: If you are needing to accept anything with slashes, then `api.add_resource(Endpoint, '/<path:content>')` should work

Answer (score 4):

[The comment posted by cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627804/catch-all-url-in-flask-restful/55490601#comment66561311_39627804) solved the problem:

> If you are needing to accept anything with slashes, then `api.add_resource(Endpoint, '/<path:content>')` should work